# Transforming a sftp shell script command into a ftp command

Tags: bash, shell, ftp, sftp

I am writing my first shell script ever and trying to figure out how to transform this command:

```
sftp -o IdentityFile=/home/test/test/id_dsa test@test.test.com < sftp_put.txt;
```

into an equivalent command where I connect to a ftp server. The key difference is that I will be logging into this server via a username and password not my ssh credentials. Note I am trying to upload two files.

Again any help would be more than appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.netrc` for this:

```
$ cat > .netrc
machine your.machine.ip.address
login your.login.name
^D
$ ftp your.machine.ip.address < ftp_cmds.txt
```

Which would prompt you for a password. If you're okay with it, you can save the password (clear text) in .netrc to skip this prompt. See `man netrc` for more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
   ftp -v -n <<EOF > ${LOG_FTP} 2>&1
   open ${IP_ADDRESS_SERVER}
   user ${FTPUSER} ${FTPPASS}
   cd ${REMOTE_DIR}
   put sftp_put.txt
EOF
```